# Run-time Error when Deserializing Trait

Tags: scala, spray

Given a sealed trait, as well as 2 sub-classes:

```
import spray.json._

sealed trait HasColor {
    val hasColor: Boolean = true
}

sealed trait Ball {
    val name: String
    val age: Int
}
case class GreenBall(name: String, age: Int) extends Ball with HasColor

case class SimpleBall(name: String, age: Int) extends Ball

object GreenBall {
    import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

    implicit val format: RootJsonFormat[GreenBall] = 
        jsonFormat2(GreenBall.apply)
}

object SimpleBall {
    import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

    implicit val format: RootJsonFormat[SimpleBall] = 
        jsonFormat2(SimpleBall.apply)
}
```

I attempted to define a `BallFormat` that would define how to (de)serialize a JSON -> `Ball`, and vice-versa. For this question, I don't care about how the `write` method gets implemented.

```
object Ball {

    implicit object BallFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Ball] {

        override def write(ball: Ball): JsValue = 
            ???

        override def read(json: JsValue): Ball = json match {
            case JsObject(fields) =>
                fields.get("hasColor") match {
                    case None    => json.convertTo[SimpleBall]
                    case Some(_) => json.convertTo[GreenBall]
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This code compiles, but attempting to use it shows a run-time error:

```
scala>import spray.json._

scala>import net._
scala> """ { "name" : "foo", "age": 55, "hasColor" : true } """.parseJson
res1: spray.json.JsValue = {"name":"foo","age":55,"hasColor":true}

scala> res1.convertTo[Ball]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot automatically determine case 
       class field names and order for 'net.GreenBall', 
          please use the 'jsonFormat' overload with explicit field name specification
  at spray.json.ProductFormats$class.extractFieldNames(ProductFormats.scala:84)
  at spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol$.extractFieldNames(DefaultJsonProtocol.scala:30)
  at spray.json.ProductFormatsInstances$class.jsonFormat2(ProductFormatsInstances.scala:43)
  at spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol$.jsonFormat2(DefaultJsonProtocol.scala:30)
  at net.GreenBall$.<init>(Ball.scala:21)
  at net.GreenBall$.<clinit>(Ball.scala)
  at net.Ball$BallFormat$.read(Ball.scala:42)
  at net.Ball$BallFormat$.read(Ball.scala:33)
  at spray.json.JsValue.convertTo(JsValue.scala:31)
  ... 43 elided
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Case class net.GreenBall declares additional fields
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at spray.json.ProductFormats$class.extractFieldNames(ProductFormats.scala:79)
  ... 51 more
```

What's the reason for this run-time error?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I don't think the macro expansion works with fields defined into the trait which are extend by the case class, in your case your class extends `HasColor` but it does't _implement_ the `hasColor` field.

Comment: You might want to check https://github.com/cvogt/play-json-extensions

Comment: play-json-extensions has a similar problem. You need a non-optional discriminator field between the two cases.

Answer (score 2):

The `jsonformat` methods provided by `DefaultJsonProtocol` don't support fields added by mixed in traits. This means that you will have to write a full `RootJsonFormat` for your `GreenBall` class instead of using `jsonFormat`.

There is at least one library built on top of spray-json that has out-of-the-box support for serializing sealed trait hierarchies. Have a look at [spray-json-shapeless](https://github.com/fommil/spray-json-shapeless)